# eclipse plugins: How to add entries to Show View menu?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am wondering if there is a way of adding some of my plugin views to this  [Alt+Shift+Q menu](http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2010/02/15/the-fastest-ways-to-navigate-views-in-eclipse-using-the-keyboard/):


[image: ALT+Shift+Q]

Or, how could I make another one looking just like this, with other shortcut keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the ambiguous keystroke resolution menu. It shows you anything that has a key binding starting with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

So you just need to have a key binding for a show view command for your view.

For example, the following is the binding for 'Show View (Problems)':

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
  <key
        sequence="M2+M3+Q X"
        contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
        commandId="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration">
        <parameter 
            id="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView.viewId"
            value="org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView" />
  </key>
```

The `value` attribute of the `<parameter>` element defines the view to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

So, in the `plugin.xml`, I added:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">   
    <key
        sequence="M2+M3+Q K"
        contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
        commandId="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration">
        <parameter 
            id="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView.viewId"
            value="my.plugin.views.GraphView" />   
    </key> 
</extension>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it like this, starting with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
  <key
        sequence="M2+M3+X G"
        contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
        commandId="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration">
        <parameter 
            id="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView.viewId"
            value="my.plugin.views.GraphView" />
  </key>
</extension>
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
  <key
        sequence="M2+M3+X C"
        contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
        commandId="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration">
        <parameter 
            id="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView.viewId"
            value="my.plugin.views.Connections" />
  </key>
</extension>
```

And thus you create another view section:

[image]